# Remove JS file from Woocommerce Product edit pages

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, jquery-select2, wordpress-hook

I am getting this error "Uncaught Error: Option 'ajax' is not allowed for Select2 when attached to a  element." while updating Product Variation.

Actually there are 2 select2.js files, one from Woocommerce and other from 'WR PageBuilder' plugin. While I am renaming 'WR PageBuilder' select2.js file then its working fine. But that file is required for Editor.

I want to remove that js file only from Product pages.

I did 'wp_deregister_script()' and 'wp_dequeue_script()' but nothing happened.

Here is my code:

```
add_action('admin_init', 'functon_to_filter_script');
function functon_to_filter_script() {
global $typenow;
// when editing pages, $typenow isn't set until later!
if (empty($typenow)) {
    // try to pick it up from the query string
    if (!empty($_GET['post'])) {
        $post = get_post($_GET['post']);
        $typenow = $post->post_type;
    }
}
if( 'product' == $typenow ){
    add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'deregister_my_script', 100 );

}
}
function deregister_my_script() {
  wp_dequeue_script('wr-pagebuilder');
  wp_deregister_script('wr-pagebuilder');
}
```

can anyone give me a solution?

Answer (score 0):

This won't work because you are using the actions wrong.
Look here for the correct usage of action hooks:
[Hooks in Wordpress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference)

You are putting the admin_enqueue_scripts action hook inside of the admin_init action hook.
Try taking admin_enqueue_scripts outside of the admin_init hook like this:

```
global $typenow;

add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'deregister_my_script', 100 );


function deregister_my_script() {
    if (!empty($_GET['post'])) {
        $post = get_post($_GET['post']);
        $typenow = $post->post_type;
    }

    if( 'product' == $typenow ){
        wp_dequeue_script('wr-pagebuilder');
        wp_deregister_script('wr-pagebuilder');
    }

}
```

Comment: I did that but no luck with that.

Comment: What was the problem?

Comment: I did that my way :). Removed js file from 'WR PageBuilder' plugin and then hook again from function.php for all the pages excpet product page. And now it works fine :)

Comment: Cool. You should add the answer in.